# Net Core 3 with Entity Core global - dotnet-ef with Debian

Tags: linux, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm having trouble running the Entity Framework.

I downloaded the Net Core 3.0 preview6.tar on microsoft's website.
I unzipped, and moved to

/ opt / net_core / skd_3
and created a symbolic link to / bin

and now when I run dotnet anywhere it works.

Then I performed:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10
```

But when I try to do dotnet-ef
always return the error:

```
A fatal error occurred. The required library libhostfxr.so could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [/home/rodrigo/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-ef/3.0.0-preview6.19304.10/dotnet-ef/3.0.0-preview6. 19304.10 / tools / netcoreapp3.0 / any /].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [/ usr / share / dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [/ etc / dotnet / install_location].
```

Could someone help?